# alpine docker: installing pandas / numpy

Tags: python, pandas, docker, alpine-linux

I install py3-pandas as following,

```
 FROM alpine:latest

 RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
 RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories


 RUN apk add --update \
   python3 \
   python3-dev \
   py3-numpy py3-pandas py3-scipy py3-numpy-dev
```

Then I try to import pandas, it's not avaialble

```
bash-5.0# python3
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:25:15)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/retention']
>>>
```

So it turns out pandas are installed in the different python directory

```
bash-5.0# apk info -L py3-pandas
....
usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc


bash-5.0# ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python             /usr/bin/python2.7          /usr/bin/python3-config     /usr/bin/python3.7-config   /usr/bin/python3.7m-config
/usr/bin/python2            /usr/bin/python3            /usr/bin/python3.7          /usr/bin/python3.7m
```

How do I make `py3-pandas` to use the python version which is already installed in the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing your versions - your Dockerfile is using `latest` but you're including "edge" repositories.

To use Python 3.7 (no testing repo), you could use the following:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
```

but you risk changing versions in the future. Best to use:

```
FROM alpine:3.10

RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
```

If you really want Python 3.8 and "testing" repo, you'll have to use `latest` (again at the risk of changing versions):

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
```

Comment: Just one point: **latest** and **numbered** versions does not has `testing` packages, just **edge** version!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to set the [PYTONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable in the Dockerfile.

> Augment the default search path for module files. The format is the
>   same as the shell’s PATH: one or more directory pathnames separated by
>   os.pathsep (e.g. colons on Unix or semicolons on Windows).
>   Non-existent directories are silently ignored.

```
RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo "http://dl-8.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories
ENV PYTHONPATH /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```